# How to show a php or html file with output buffering

Tags: php

I am trying to display a index file using the `ob` functions. I am very close to getting it,  the only problem is not everything is correct. When the file loads only some of the css files are being used. They both seem to be included correctly but only one is applied not all of them. Is there something wrong with the set of functions I am using? Maybe I need to use different ones?

here is the method that gets the contents.

```
public function get($file)
{
    if(file_exists($file))
    {
        ob_start();

        include $file;
        $out1 = ob_get_contents();

        return $out1;
    }
    else
    {
        return "File not found.";
    }
}
```

`$file` can be any html file like the one below:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css" type="text/css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/screen.css" type="text/css"/>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lekton:400,700,400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <script src="js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container_border">
            <div id="contact_info">
                <ul>
                    <li>Email: <a href="mailto:test@google.com">test@google.com</a></li>
                    <li>Phone: <a href="tel:123345355">123345355</a></li>
                    <li>Quality products &amp; hassle-free service.</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="row" id="header_bg">
                <img src="img/logo.png" alt="Physician Associates Logo" id="logo">
            </div>

            <div class="row" style="background-color: #f5f5f5;">
                <div class="medium-6 columns main_padding" id="container_content">
                    <h1>Who We Are</h1>
                    <p>
                        We like to keep things simple. Contact us today using our form to request more information, or call us directly. We appreciate your business! 
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="medium-6 columns main_padding" id="container_form">
                    <form action="contact.php" method="post">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="medium-6 columns">
                                <label for="name">Name</label><input class="input_custom" name="name" type="text">
                            </div>
                            <div class="medium-6 columns">
                                <label for="name">Practice</label><input class="input_custom" name="practice" type="text">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="medium-12">
                            <label for="email">E-mail</label><input class="input_custom" name="email" size="50" type="text">
                        </div>

                        <div class="medium-12">
                            <label for="subject">Subject</label><input class="input_custom" name="subject" size="50" type="text">
                        </div>

                        <label for="message">Message</label>
                            <textarea name="message"></textarea>
                        <input class="button small radius" value="Send" type="submit">
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
        <script>
          $(document).foundation();
        </script>
        <script>
            (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
            (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
            m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
            })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

            ga('create', 'UA-47882868-1', 'physicianassociates.com');
            ga('send', 'pageview');
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

when the `get()` method return the content it simple echoed thats all. When I inspect element on the page the html source looks exactly like the code above. All the images show just fine but not all the css shows only certain files. The files are included and I have no errors saying they can not be found.

Comment: You aren't doing anything with `$out1`. Your code might as well not use the output buffering functions at all. You'll need to provide examples of what you expect to see and what you're actually seeing in order to even begin to debug your problem.

Comment: @Phil sorry about that fixed the error. Still no go on the css :(

Comment: Why are you even bothering doing this? You seem to be performing the tasks that a web server does quite well (fetching files by name and showing them via HTTP).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't ending or flushing the output buffer so you're most definitely going to run into trouble.

I suggest you use [`ob_get_clean()`](http://php.net/manual/function.ob-get-clean.php) instead, eg

```
ob_start();
include $file;
return ob_get_clean();
```

Comment: unfortunately when I use the code above then none of the css works at that point :(

Comment: @zachstarnes You'll have to explain what that means. Do you have any console errors for missing CSS files? What does the rendered HTML source look like (assuming this has something to do with HTML)?

Comment: there are no errors about missing css files that is what is confusing me what shows is just plain html and images with no css applied. The HTML source looks normal.

Comment: @zachstarnes There's no way to help you debug this if you're not going to provide the necessary information. What's in `$file`? What do you do with the value returned from `get()`? **What does the rendered HTML source look like?**

Comment: I apologize for not giving more info. Please see the update above

Comment: @zachstarnes Ok, so you've shown what a `$file` can look like. For the last time, **what does the rendered HTML source look like?** Don't use use the DOM inspector / *Elements* tab, view the actual page source. Also, check your *Network* tab for the CSS files and inspect the responses.